# Generated debug APK is not installable after updating Android gradle and plugin version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I'm unable to install debug apk in emulator or any other devices after updating Android gradle version from 6.5 to 7.3.3 and plugin version from 4.1.2 to 7.2.0.

Getting this below error message while installing an apk :

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
    List of apks:
    [0] 'C:\Users\...\Documents\Android\app\build\intermediates\apk\_int\debug\my.....apk'
    The APKs are invalid.
    Retry
    Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

Could you please help me? How I can resolve this issue? I have seen many SO answers tried some solutions like clean, rebuild, invalid cache and restart but still getting the same issue.

Comment: try to delete your `app/build` folder and then try to `clean` and `rebuild` your project

Comment: @AbhishekPatel already tried all the options but no luck.

Comment: Try to remove old APK `debug/app-debug.apk` in the folder.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel yes have tried this too

Comment: Try to clean the build then install it again. Also, remove the previous build from the phone then try again

Comment: @SumitKumawat all these basics stuff have tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Choose APK After Click on Build and Generate Signed Bundle / APK...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOtwH.png)

[Next Create or choose a Key Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md5wc.png)

[Then tho most important you create Release and not debug, after you'll be able to install your APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NpZs.png)

Comment: If I want to test an app in emulator then how I can test it ?

Comment: On top right there is a play button to launch the app, you don't need to buid it before

Comment: Or normally you can just press control + r (I'm on mac idk for Window)

Comment: when I'm running debug variant in emulator so still getting this error "The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK"

Comment: Which emulator are you using ?

Comment: Do you have the Default APK in the Run/Debug Configurations ?

Comment: I'm using Pixel 5 emulator. Yes have Default APK in the Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: Did you try an emulator with Play Store ? like Pixel 2 API 30

Comment: yes have tried with play store also...still faced the same issue.

Comment: For me just deleted the debug folder was good, so I don't really understand for you 

Comment: It's probably in your build.gradle there is a problem

Comment: yeah same...1st time am facing this type of issue. unable to debug it.

Comment: If I create release build then its installable but the debug build is showing above mentioned issue. anything need to be change for debug build types ?